# Shuffle 2D vector by column

Tags: c++, vector, 2d, shuffle

My current code shuffles the 2d vector by row, but now I want to shuffle the vector by column. I need to do them one at a time in order to preserve a certain property (the n-rooks property in multijittered sampling).

I know this seems like a trivial question that has probably been asked countless times, but I spent the last 40 minutes trying to google it and apparently my google skills are trash.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>



int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> v { {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {3,6,9} };

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           std::cout << v[i][j] << " ";
       }
       std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;

   unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
   shuffle(v.begin(),v.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           std::cout << v[i][j] << " ";
       }
       std::cout << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 4 7 
2 5 8 
3 6 9 

3 6 9 
1 4 7 
2 5 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to shuffle each inner vector with the same "random" engine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> v { {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {3,6,9} };

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           std::cout << v[i][j] << " ";
       }
       std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;

   unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
   for (auto &inner : v) {
      shuffle(inner.begin(),inner.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           std::cout << v[i][j] << " ";
       }
       std::cout << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this shuffling the rows, not the columns?

Comment: @NathanOliver OP wants to shuffle "by column", in other words take whole columns and swap them with other columns. It's equivalent to shuffling a row and all other rows the same way.

Comment: Oh, okay.  Wasn't sure but that makes sense now.

Comment: Does this shuffle the elements in each row the same way each iteration because the same seed is provided to the shuffle function on each iteration? Also, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, the engines generate the same sequences because of the same seed.